# Adding "Related Products" to a custom tab in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce, product

I'm having trouble adding "Related Products" to a tab and making it work on posts that are used with a short code. Here's the short code and complete code that's being placed in my functions.php

**[product_page id="99"]**

Here's the code i'm using in my themes functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
/*
 * Register custom tab
 */
function woo_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

   $custom_tab = array( 
        'custom_tab' =>  array( 
                            'title' => __('Custom Tab','woocommerce'), 
                            'priority' => 9, 
                            'callback' => 'woo_custom_product_tab_content' 
                        )
                );
return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}
/*
* Place content in custom tab (related products in this sample)
*/
function woo_custom_product_tab_content() {
woocommerce_related_products();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab' );
```

**Here's the error i'm receiving:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_upsells() on a non-object in public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/up-sells.php on line 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the global $product object with [WC_Product **`get_related()`** method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_related) to avoid this error…

Then the solution could be:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
/*
 * Register custom tab
 */
function woo_custom_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $custom_tab = array( 
        'custom_tab' =>  array( 
            'title' => __('Custom Tab','woocommerce'), 
            'priority' => 9, 
            'callback' => 'woo_custom_product_tab_content' 
        )
    );
    return array_merge( $custom_tab, $tabs );
}

/*
* Place content in custom tab (related products in this sample)
*/
function woo_custom_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    $product->get_related();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tab' );
```

As this is untested, I doesn't guaranty anything…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: That works! however, that is only working with the shortcode, but not working on woocommerce pages… any solution?